# How can I select two different values from another table using only a single query?

Tags: mysql, join

I have a `user` table with user names, and a `message` table with `from_id` and `to_id`. How can I get *from user name* and *to user name* using only a single query?

I have used the below query but something is wrong:

```
select id,name 
from   user
where  'id' not in (select 'from_id' from message) and
       'id' not in (select 'to_ID' from message);
```

**`user` table**

[image: user table]

**`message` table**

[image: message table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT m.id 'message_id',
       `u1`.`name` `from_name`,
       `u2`.`name` `to_name`
FROM   `message` `m`
JOIN   `user` `u1` ON `m`.`from_id` = `u1`.`id`
JOIN   `user` `u2` ON `m`.`to_id`   = `u2`.`id`
```

Comment: Is this working? Inorder to look better click edit, select all and press Ctrl+K.Then save edits

Comment: Shouldn't `message_id` be in backticks?

Answer (score 0):

to get user name and id of user 
`select id, name from user u, message m where u.id=m.from_ID and u.id=m.to_ID`

Comment: MySQL returned an empty result set (i.e. zero rows).  not working

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT from.name as FromUser, to.name AS ToUser 
FROM user AS from, user AS to, (SELECT * FROM message where id=somevalue) AS m 
WHERE from.emp_id = m.from_id AND to.emp_id=m.to_id;
```